# Switch to test for id and perform action based on class

Tags: javascript

I have a number of elements on a page which may have a background colour pink, yellow or blue. These elements all carry a respective class, for example blue:

```
<a href="http://somesite.com/person/Arnald_Garnier_MSP-AU" class="change_link_colour doc-person-blue">Arnaldus Garnieri</a>
```

I have three buttons for removing each of these respective background colours,

```
<span id="clear-doc-person-blue" class="fake_link" onclick="clearentitycolour(this.id)">clear all</span>

<span id="clear-doc-place-pink" class="fake_link" onclick="clearentitycolour(this.id)">clear all</span>

<span id="clear-doc-segment-yellow" class="fake_link" onclick="clearentitycolour(this.id)">clear all</span>
```

The buttons call to the same function, which should read the element id name and determine which class to select for updating all `style.backgroundColor = "none"`

```
function clearentitycolour(clicked_id)
   {
       switch(clicked_id) {
       case "clear-doc-person-blue":
       var x = document.getElementsByClassName("doc-person-blue");
       var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.backgroundColor = "none";}
       break;
       case "clear-doc-place-pink":
       var x = document.getElementsByClassName("doc-place-pink");
       var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.backgroundColor = "none";}
       break;
       case "clear-doc-segment-yellow":
       var x = document.getElementsByClassName("doc-segment-yellow");
       var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.backgroundColor = "none";}
       break;
       }}
```

It doesn't do anything, and I don't see why.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working fine; just one bug – instead of `background-color: 'none'` you have to use `background-color: 'transparent'`.

```js
function clearentitycolour(clicked_id)
   {
     console.log(clicked_id)
       switch(clicked_id) {
       case "clear-doc-person-blue":
       var x = document.getElementsByClassName("doc-person-blue");
           
       var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.backgroundColor = "transparent";}
       break;
       case "clear-doc-place-pink":
       var x = document.getElementsByClassName("doc-place-pink");
       var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.backgroundColor = "transparent";}
       break;
       case "clear-doc-segment-yellow":
       var x = document.getElementsByClassName("doc-segment-yellow");
       var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.backgroundColor = "transparent";}
       break;
       }}
```

```css
.doc-person-blue {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<span id="clear-doc-person-blue" class="fake_link" onclick="clearentitycolour(this.id)">clear blue</span>

<a href="http://somesite.com/person/Arnald_Garnier_MSP-AU" class="change_link_colour doc-person-blue">Arnaldus Garnieri</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

On click you have to pass only *this*
Then you switch the *id*

*None* is not a valid value, you need to use *transparent*

```
x[i].style["background-color"] = "transparent";
```

```js
function clearentitycolour(clicked_id)
   {
   
   
       switch(clicked_id.id) {
       case "clear-doc-person-blue":
       var x = document.getElementsByClassName("doc-person-blue");
       var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style["background-color"] = "transparent";}
       break;
       case "clear-doc-place-pink":
       var x = document.getElementsByClassName("doc-place-pink");
       var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style["background-color"] = "transparent";}
       break;
       case "clear-doc-segment-yellow":
       var x = document.getElementsByClassName("doc-segment-yellow");
       var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style["background-color"] = "transparent";}
       break;
       }}
```

```css
.doc-person-blue {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://somesite.com/person/Arnald_Garnier_MSP-AU" class="change_link_colour doc-person-blue">Arnaldus Garnieri</a>
I have three buttons for removing each of these respective background colours,

<span id="clear-doc-person-blue" class="fake_link" onclick="clearentitycolour(this)">clear all</span>

<span id="clear-doc-place-pink" class="fake_link" onclick="clearentitycolour(this)">clear all</span>

<span id="clear-doc-segment-yellow" class="fake_link" onclick="clearentitycolour(this)">clear all</span>
The buttons call to the same function, which should read the element id name and determine which class to select for updating all style.backgroundColor = "none"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at the code, there is really no need to have the switch statement in this instance. Perhaps could be trimmed to this.

```js
function clearentitycolour(classToClear)
{
    console.log(classToClear);
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName(classToClear);      

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    }
}
```

```css
.doc-person-blue {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<span id="clear-doc-person-blue" class="fake_link" onclick="clearentitycolour('doc-person-blue')">clear all</span>

<span id="clear-doc-place-pink" class="fake_link" onclick="clearentitycolour('doc-place-pink')">clear all</span>

<span id="clear-doc-segment-yellow" class="fake_link" onclick="clearentitycolour('doc-segment-yellow')">clear all</span>

<a href="http://somesite.com/person/Arnald_Garnier_MSP-AU" class="change_link_colour doc-person-blue">Arnaldus Garnieri</a>
```

Comment: That's a very nice solution, thanks! I'm still new to javascript: is the `console.log` just for demonstration purposes here?

Comment: Yes, think of the console as a way of getting debug information without interfering with you code.